# How to create a member vector of filtering streams?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, boost-iostreams

Let's start with a simple compressed file reader class using `boost::iostreams`:

```
class SingleFileOpener{
    public:
        SingleFileOpener(const std::string& filename, bool is_compressed) {
            if(is_compressed) m_stream.push(bio::zlib_decompressor());
            m_stream.push(bio::file_source{filename});
        }

        void print() {
            bio::copy(m_stream, std::cout);
        }
    private:
        using unseekable_stream = boost::iostreams::filtering_istream;
        unseekable_stream m_stream;
};
```

Now calling `SingleFileOpener("input.txt", true)` followed by `print()` works correctly. [**Coliru Link**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/391058f919bbfaed)

I want to extend my class to read and manipulate multiple files in a similar manner. Below is the sample code I tried out(commented out in the Coliru link above too):

```
class MultiFileOpener{
    public:
        MultiFileOpener(const std::vector<std::string> filenames, std::vector<bool> is_compressed) {
            for(auto i = 0u; i < filenames.size(); i++) {
                unseekable_stream s;
                if(is_compressed[i]) s.push(bio::zlib_decompressor());
                s.push(bio::file_source{filenames[i]});
                m_stream.emplace_back(s); // <- error: use of deleted function(copy ctor)
            }
        }

        void print(int i) {
            bio::copy(*m_stream[i], std::cout);
        }
    private:
        using unseekable_stream = boost::iostreams::filtering_istream;
        std::vector<boost::optional<unseekable_stream>> m_stream;
};
```

The above doesnt compile due to missing copy constructors in base classes. I've tried using `boost::optional`, `std::shared_ptr` and miscellaneous alternatives used for delayed initialization. Uptil now the only solution that has worked is to use an initializer list constructor for the `std::vector`, i.e. doing `ctor: m_stream(filenames.size()) {...}`. I had 2 questions:

1. Why is a copy constructor even being called here?
2. Is it possible to do this without the initializer list way?

Comment: Can you indicate which line your compiler is choking on, please?

Comment: have indicated as a comment

Comment: when you say you tried `std::shared_ptr`, do you mean that you were not able to use a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<unseekable_stream>>`? That would require `unseekable_stream s;` to be `std::shared_ptr<unseekable_stream> s(new unseekable_stream);`

Comment: Yes, shared_ptr does work - i had made a mistake in my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is a copy constructor even being called here?

Here:

```
m_stream.emplace_back(s);
```

---

> Is it possible to do this without the initializer list way?

**Option 1**

Use a list:

```
    std::list<unseekable_stream> m_stream;
```

Change the for loop as follows:

```
m_stream.emplace_back();
auto& s = m_stream.back();
if(is_compressed[i]) s.push(bio::zlib_decompressor());
s.push(bio::file_source{filenames[i]});
```

---

**Option 2**

Use `unique_ptr`:

```
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<unseekable_stream>> m_stream;
```

For loop code:

```
auto stream_ptr = std::make_unique<unseekable_stream>();
... //same as above but change . to ->
m_stream.push_back(std::move(stream_ptr));
```

---

**Option 3**

Initialize vector with size and not use `push_back` or `emplace_back`.

```
std::vector<unseekable_stream> m_stream;

MultiFileOpener(const std::vector<std::string>& filenames, const std::vector<bool>& is_compressed) 
 : m_stream(filenames.size())
   {
        for(auto i = 0u; i < filenames.size(); i++) {
            unseekable_stream& s = m_stream[i];
            if(is_compressed[i]) s.push(bio::zlib_decompressor());
            s.push(bio::file_source{filenames[i]});
        }
    }
```

With this, you cannot add or remove streams later. If those features are needed, use the other options.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on (1) - I've even tried `std::move(s)` and it fails

Comment: filtering_stream does not have both copy and move constructor, you have to directly create it inside the container and then refer it. vector cannot contain types that is neither movable nor copyable. So use a list like in my example.

Comment: I'm no expert on boost, but I would expect it doesn't like the move because s is declared in scope, and it wants to be intact when it automatically gets destroyed on exiting the scope.

Comment: This has nothing to do with boost, `move` does not work because, move constructor is not declared.

Comment: Thanks, just for future reference heres a code link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/928aa94ee5ff834d

Comment: other option is to use `vector<unique_ptr<unseekable_stream>>`, e.g. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r1YH_T